# Como usar '.each()' em uma variável para obter vários '.attr()' de uma lista?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou a começar a desenvolver uma galeria de videos no qual vou fazer *upload* para o GitHub para quem quiser fazer download e uso dela.

Eu tenho uma lista da seguinte maneira:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="everyVideo ytVideo" data-videoID="6AmRg3p79pM">Video 1</span></li>
    <li><span class="everyVideo ytVideo" data-videoID="El3IZFGERbM">Video 1</span></li>
    <!-- continua... -->
</ul>
```

Em cada item da lista, irei pegar o `data-videoID="El3IZFGERbM"` para poder criar uma caixa/div de video, onde o vídeo será gerado para reprodução.

No entanto da maneira que estou a fazer, só estou a conseguir pegar o primeiro `data-video` da lista:

```
var videoID = $('.everyVideo').attr('data-videoID');
```

Eu até já tentei usar o `.each()` nesta `var` acima, mas não estou conseguindo ter resultados positivos.

```
var videoID = $('.everyVideo').each(function (index, value){ $(this).attr('data-videoID'); });
```

Abaixo vou colocar um snippet de um excerto do código em que estou a trabalhar no momento no qual estou tentando resolver este problema:

```js
var ytTarget = $('#videoGallery .ytVideo');
var videoID = $('.everyVideo').attr('data-videoID');

// Video and thumnnails incorporation vars
var ytVideo = $('<div id="meuVideo"> <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ videoID +'?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>');
var ytThumb = $('<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+ videoID +'/default.jpg"/>');

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.everyVideo').hasClass('ytVideo')){
    $('.ytVideo').append(ytThumb);
  } else {

  }
});

// Youtube Video
ytTarget.click(function(){
  $('#meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
  ytVideo.insertAfter('.vidPlayer').hide().slideDown("fast");
});

// Fechar Videos
$('#close').click(function(){
  $('#meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
});
```

```css
.everyVideo, #close {cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="videoGallery">
<div class="vidPlayer"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="everyVideo ytVideo" data-videoID="6AmRg3p79pM">Video 1</span></li>
        <li><span class="everyVideo ytVideo" data-videoID="El3IZFGERbM">Video 4</span></li>
        <li><span id="close">Fechar Tudo</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Na segunda imagem que aparece, tanto a imagem como o video que aparece ao clicarmos no elemento, deveria ser um video diferente. Como faço para resolver isso?

> Quaisquer melhorias de código serão bem-vindas e uma nota (juntamente com o link da sua conta GitHub/site) será incluída no projeto pela sua ajuda! Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz uma iteração a partir de `'.ytVideo'` e faz o append a esse elemento dentro do `.each`. Algo assim:

```js
var ytTarget = $('#videoGallery .ytVideo');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ytVideo').each(function() {
        var videoID = $(this).attr('data-videoID');
        var ytVideo = $('<div id="meuVideo"> <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoID + '?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>');
        var ytThumb = $('<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + videoID + '/default.jpg"/>');
        $(this).append(ytThumb);
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('#meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
            ytVideo.insertAfter('.vidPlayer').hide().slideDown("fast");
        });
    });
});

// Fechar Videos
$('#close').click(function() {
    $('#meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
});
```

```css
.everyVideo, #close {cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="videoGallery">
<div class="vidPlayer"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="everyVideo ytVideo" data-videoID="6AmRg3p79pM">Video 1</span></li>
        <li><span class="everyVideo ytVideo" data-videoID="El3IZFGERbM">Video 4</span></li>
        <li><span id="close">Fechar Tudo</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sergio ! Andava eu aqui há bué de volta disto, e o código está bem melhor arrumadinho ;)